# Symfony 4 - Dynamic Generation for Submitted Forms with Select2

Tags: symfony, jquery-select2, symfony4, symfony-forms

I'm following the tutorial at http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms

I managed to reproduce the tutorial without worries, everything works well. However, when I apply "Select2" on my fields, it does not work anymore.

### Form :

```
class TicketAdminForm extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('Client', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Clients::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'label' => "Client",
                'placeholder' => '',
                'attr' => ['data-provider' => 'select2'],
            ])
        ;

        $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Clients $client = null) {
            $entity = null === $client ? [] : $client->getEntities();

            $form->add('entity', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'App\Entity\Entity',
                'placeholder' => '',
                'choices' => $entity,
                'label' => 'Entité',
                'attr' => ['data-provider' => 'select2'],
            ]);
        };

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                // this would be your entity, i.e. Clients
                $data = $event->getData();
                $form = $event->getForm();

                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getClient());
            }
        );

        $builder->get('Client')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                // It's important here to fetch $event->getForm()->getData(), as
                // $event->getData() will get you the client data (that is, the ID)
                $client = $event->getForm()->getData();

                // since we've added the listener to the child, we'll have to pass on
                // the parent to the callback functions!
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $client);
            }
        );
    }
```

### Twig :

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal'} }) }}
        <div class="box-body">
            {{ form_row(form.client) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.client) }}
            {{ form_row(form.entity) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.entity) }}
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-body -->

        <div class="box-footer">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8">

                <button id="dropbutton" class="btn bg-ticketing btn-flat form-control" type="submit">
                    {{ 'Submit the ticket'|trans({}, 'TicketingBundle') }}
                </button>


            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-footer -->
        {{ form_end(form) }}
    </div>

    <script>
        var $client = $('#ticket_admin_form_client');
        // When client gets selected ...
        $client.change(function() {
            console.log('dans change');
            // ... retrieve the corresponding form.
            var $form = $(this).closest('form');
            // Simulate form data, but only include the selected client value.
            var data = {};
            data[$client.attr('name')] = $client.val();
            // Submit data via AJAX to the form's action path.
            $.ajax({
                url : $form.attr('action'),
                type: $form.attr('method'),
                data : data,
                success: function(html) {
                    // Replace current entity field ...
                    $('#ticket_admin_form_entity').replaceWith(
                        // ... with the returned one from the AJAX response.
                        $(html).find('#ticket_admin_form_entity')
                    );
                    // Entity field now displays the appropriate entities.
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This code only works if I remove `'attr' => ['data-provider' => 'select2']` in form.

I tried :

```
$('#ticket_admin_form_client').on("select2:selecting", function(e) { 
   console.log('test');
});
```

but it does not work.

Do you have a solution to make it work with select2?

Comment: "it does not work (anymore)" isn't really helpful at all. what precisely doesn't work? are there error messages in the browser console? if yes, it would be wise to share them. if no, you should really describe what you expected to happen, and what did happen. we have little to no information here.

Comment: When I apply `'attr' => ['data-provider' => 'select2']` to the client field in the form, the function `$client.change(function () {});` does not work anymore. I feel like it's var $client = $('# ticket_admin_form_client'); which does not work. I do not have any code in the console

Comment: that would make sense, if select2 overrides `$client.change`, in which case, it's not a symfony problem ... I don't know select2 well enough, but maybe select2 has its own concept to hook into the change event?

Comment: anyway: to be certain you have the right id: `$client = $('#{{ form.client.vars.id }}');` should provide you with the correct id for the select field, in case the id magically changed when rendering with additional data-properties ......

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, in your ajax method add this :

```js
 $('#ticket_admin_form_entity').select2({});
```

Like this in method `success` by this :

```js
// ...

$.ajax({
 // ...
 success: function(html) {
    
     $('#ticket_admin_form_entity').replaceWith(
        $(html).find('#ticket_admin_form_entity')
     );
     
     $('#ticket_admin_form_entity').select2({}); // Add this 
}

// ...
```

;)